# Solubility of NOx gases

Tags: solubility, analytical-chemistry

Are the oxides of nitrogen (such as $\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{NO2}$) emitted from the exhaust of a diesel engine soluble? If so, in what solvents is it soluble?

I want to analyse the nitrogen oxides in the exhaust gas of a diesel engine. Is it possible to collect the gas by solvent extraction method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\ce{NO_x}$ can be quantitatively removed from such combustion streams by absorption/dissolution in basic aqueous solutions containing an appropriate oxidizing agent. While $\ce{NO2}$ is readily soluble in aqueous solution, $\ce{NO}$ is not. However, $\ce{NO}$ is easily converted to $\ce{NO2}$ when an oxidant is added to the solution.

The [PhD thesis by Chen-Lu Yang at NJIT](http://archives.njit.edu/vol01/etd/1990s/1990/njit-etd1990-007/njit-etd1990-007.pdf), "*Aqueous Absorption of $\ce{NO_x}$ Induced by Sodium Chlorite Oxidation*", concluded the following:

- $\ce{NO2}$ is essentially quantitatively absorbed in $\ce{NaOH}$ aqueous scrubbing solutions.
- $\ce{NO}$ is not absorbed by $\ce{NaOH}$ aqueous scrubbing solutions.
- $\ce{NaClO2}$ containing aqueous scrubbing medium quantitatively oxidizes $\ce{NO}$ to nitrate [which is highly water soluble].

The net effect of these solubility/reactivity properties is that $\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{NO2}$ can be quantitatively removed from a gas stream using an aqueous solution of $\ce{NaOH}$ and $\ce{NaClO2}$

Additionally, according to [this PubChem entry](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/nitric_oxide#section=Top), $\ce{NO}$ is soluble in sulfuric acid, ethanol and carbon disulfide, while according to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_dioxide), $\ce{NO2}$ is soluble in carbon tetrachloride, nitric acid and chloroform.